# Flutter IOS error while sharing file, NSOSStatusErrorDomain

Tags: ios, flutter, share

In my application code share pdf file on whatsapp.
Its working perfectly in android, not working on ios.
My code:

```
pdfShare(BuildContext context, var url, String fileName) async {
  var response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
  final documentDirectory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  File pdfFile = File('$documentDirectory/' + fileName);
  pdfFile.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);
  Share.shareFiles([pdfFile.path], text: "View File");
}
```

await File(pdfFile.path).exists() this code returning true. Means file created.

Logs on IOS

```
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281618b90 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[_UIActivityActionCellTitleLabel:0x124b70c60]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x124b71450 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28162ae40 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' _UICollectionViewListCellContentView:0x124ba78f0.height == 30   (active)>"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2816615e0 _UIActivityActionCellTitleLabel:0x124b70c60.height >= 28.3333   (active)>
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

What should I do?